# Error response from bash script calling OCRmyPDF through Docker

Tags: linux, bash, shell, docker

**EDIT(Update):** through continued searching and testing, I've found that the problem seems to lie in the output of $PWD (or $(dirs -l) or $(pwd)) being interpreted by docker as a relative path, despite actually being absolute.

Yet, the copied, then pasted output of $PWD, $(dirs -l), $(pwd) still functions perfectly. How is this terminal-printed-output different from the *same* variable which bash is passing to docker?

---

Please bear with me, I am very new to scripting of any sort. Therefore, I'm not only sure that there is obvious redundancy within this script, but also that I am likely missing something basic.

I have written a small bash script in an attempt to convert a long-winded command, needed to run OCRmyPDF from a Docker container, into something more manageable. Here is the long command which achieves this (per the creator's github):

```
docker run -t -i -v "</path/to/pdfdir>:/home/docker/" paulstaab/ocrmypdf \  
OCRmyPDF <additional options> <pdf> <out.pdf>
```

My goal is the make a script, named **ocrmypdf**, which will take a named .pdf and any specified arguments, OCR the pdf file, and output a file with the name of the original with an '_ocr' tail.

Here is my attempt at a bash script (name of script - **ocrmypdf**):

```
#!/bin/bash
#docker ocrmypdf ease-of-use script

BASENAME=$(basename "$1")
BASENOSUFFIX=$(basename -s .pdf "$1")
DIRECTORY=$(dirs -l):/home/docker/
docker run -t -i -v \"$DIRECTORY\" paulstaab/ocrmypdf \ OCRmyPDF $2 \"$BASENAME\" \""$BASENOSUFFIX"_OCR.pdf\"
```

I know that variables might not be necessarily needed in a script this simple, but I have implemented them as I have been troubleshooting.

**The problem is** that when I run the script, focused upon a .pdf file that I know the program is able to OCR, I am returned the **error**:

```
FATA[0000] Error response from daemon: cannot bind mount volume: "/home/blue/Documents/PDF/Massumi/1995 volume paths must be absolute.
```

However, what is confusing me is that if I 'echo' the last line of the script, "docker run -t...", the *echoed* output works perfectly if copied into the terminal. For example, the output of...
(last line *echoed*)

```
./ocrmypdf test.pdf -f
```

is ('-f' forces ocrmypdf to ocr a .pdf regardless of already scanned text)

```
docker run -t -i -v "/home/blue/Documents/PDF/Massumi/1995:/home/docker/" paulstaab/ocrmypdf  OCRmyPDF -f "test.pdf" "test_OCR.pdf"
```

which, **if pasted back into the terminal, successfully OCRs the 'test.pdf'**. However, when the script is run without the last line *echoed*, I recieve the 'cannot bind mount volume' error listed above.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is lying in your `DIRECTORY` variable.
Try to put a backslash in front of the `:` in the declaration like that `DIRECTORY=$(dirs -l)\:/home/docker/`.
And you should, by safety always double quotes your variable, in this case, the `$DIRECTORY`, `$2` and `$BASENAME` in your `docker` command.

Comment: Unfortunately your suggestion and many, various attempts at quoting portions of the script still results in the error.